# Convert data type in nested JSON params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a field `loan_rate_legs` which is a JSON type

However, I want to convert the upperbound_rate, lowerbound_rate params from STRING type to Float type

```
[
  ...
  "loan_rate_legs"=>
  [{"duration"=>"6M", "upperbound_rate"=>"1.2", "lowerbound_rate"=>"17.2"},
   {"duration"=>"16M", "upperbound_rate"=>"31.2", "lowerbound_rate"=>"17.2"}
    ]}
]
```

I made a manual conversion in the following strong params method, but it looks ugly.

Any good alternative solution?

```
def loan_plan_params
  cleaned_params = params.require(:loan_plan).permit(
    :id, 
    :created_at, 
    :updated_at, 
    :loan_rate_legs => [:duration, :upperbound_rate, :lowerbound_rate]
  )
  cleaned_params['loan_rate_legs'] = cleaned_params['loan_rate_legs'].collect do |loan_rate_leg|
    {
      duration: loan_rate_leg["duration"],
      upperbound_rate: loan_rate_leg["upperbound_rate"].to_f,
      lowerbound_rate: loan_rate_leg["lowerbound_rate"].to_f,
    }
  end
  cleaned_params
end
```